# get selected dates from a range based on given days

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date range

Example Date Range:

```
const startDate = "2022-06-02";
const endDate = "2022-06-20";
```

I want to get those dates which comes on provided days array that falls between startDate & endDate

Example Array of Days:

```
["tuesday", "friday", "saturday"]
```

The expected result is :

```
2022-06-03
2022-06-04
2022-06-07
2022-06-10
2022-06-11
2022-06-14
2022-06-17
2022-06-18
```

Can anyone help me with this logic?

`What I tried was so dirty, I put a loop on range of dates, and got the list of all dates, and then i put another loop to get name of day of each date, and then compared each day name in an array of days & pushed that date to new array`

Here is the code (Which works perfectly fine) **but I need better solution**:

```
function getDaysArray(start, end) {
        
    for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
        
        arr.push(helperClass.getDateTime(new Date(dt)).date);
    }
    
    return arr;
}

function getDayName (dateStr, locale){

    var date = new Date(dateStr);

    return date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });        
}

var days = ["tuesday", "friday", "saturday"];

var getAllDates = getDaysArray("2022-06-02", "2022-06-20");
var getDates = [];
for(var i = 0; i < getAllDates.length; i++){

    if(days.includes(getDayName(getAllDates[i]).toLowerCase())){

        getDates.push(getAllDates[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try something?¿

Comment: @rustyBucketBay What I tried was so dirty, I put a loop on range of dates, and got the list of all dates, and then i put another loop to get name of day of each date, and then compared each day name in an array of days & pushed that date to new array

Comment: better to have an array of numbers, where sunday = 0 and saturday = 6. then you can just create an array of dates and filter it based on the value of [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: Please put the actual code you tried, not a description, formatted as code.

Comment: @StormTrooper, I think that you know how SO works. Should not be expecting the community work the code out for you imo. You need to show the reproducible example with the outcome you expect vs the one you obtain etc. This is a clear candidate  question where that can be done

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Look at my code so far, I assume I am asking for best practice here so doesn't seem wrong. Have a look at my edit, Thanks

Comment: @HereticMonkey Have a look at my question. I added the code I tried aswell

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an external library, the [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) library provides some helpers for this:

- [`parse`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/parse) - Return the date parsed from string using the given format string.
- [`eachDayOfInterval`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/eachDayOfInterval) - Return the array of dates within the specified time interval.
- [`getDay`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/getDay) - Get the day of the week of the given date.
- or `is*` helpers - e.g. [`isSunday`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/isSunday), [`isMonday`](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/isMonday), etc.

So if you parse your start and end dates, get a full interval range, then filter it against the days, you'll have your list.

```js
import("https://unpkg.com/date-fns@2.28.0/esm/index.js").then(({ eachDayOfInterval, getDay, parse }) => {
    const startDate = parse("2022-06-02", "yyyy-MM-dd", new Date());
    const endDate = parse("2022-06-20", "yyyy-MM-dd", new Date());
    const daysOfWeek = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];

    // Here is your list
    const daysToFilterFor = ["tuesday", "friday", "saturday"];
    const daysToFilterForIndex = daysToFilterFor.map((day) => daysOfWeek.indexOf(day));

    const range = eachDayOfInterval({
        start: startDate,
        end: endDate,
    }).filter((day) => daysToFilterForIndex.includes(getDay(day)));

    console.log(range);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Array of days to filter
const daysOff = ["Tuesday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

/**
 * @desc Determine the specific dates of days that match a given array
 * of weekdays within the range of two given dates.
 * @param {string<date>} start - The first date of the range
 * @param {string<date>} end - The last date of the range
 * @param {array<string>} weekdays - The list of days used to find the dates
 * @return {array<date>} An array of dates that correspond to weekdays
 */
function dateRanger(start, end, weekdays) {

  // Convert dates into timestamps {number}
  const A = Date.parse(start);
  const Z = Date.parse(end);

  // Seconds in a day
  const day = 86400000;
  // Determine number of days the range spans
  const total = Math.floor(((Z - A) / day) + 1);
  // Object that stores format settings for .toLocaleDateString()
  const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric'
  };

  /*
  - Instantiate an Array with room to fit the range of dates
  - On each iteration instantiate a date based on the first date then format 
    it and add it's weekday using .toLocaleDateString() 
  - Return date string as an array of pairs using .split()
  */
  const range = [...new Array(total)].map(
    (_, i) => new Date(A + (day * i))
    .toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)
    .split(', ')
  );

  /*
  - .flatMap() the first level of range to access the array of pairs
  - On each iteration compare the first value of each pair (sub[0]) with the 
    given array (weekdays).
  - If there's a match, return the second value (sub[1]) of each pair 
  - Otherwise return an empty array that gets flattened to zilch.
  */
  return range.flatMap(
    sub => weekdays.flatMap(
      day => day === sub[0] ?
      sub[1] : []
    )
  );
}

console.log(dateRanger('6-4-2022', '6-20-2022', daysOff));
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this may be not the best way to do it, but here how I did it

```js
let days = { monday: 0, tuesday: 1, wednesday: 2, thursday: 3, friday: 4, saturday: 5, sunday: 6 };
const startDate = "2022-06-02";
const endDate = "2022-06-20";
function daysindates(arr) {
    let stdate = startDate.substr(-2);
    let endate = endDate.substr(-2);
    let myarr = [],
        result = [],
        finalresult = [];
    for (y of arr) {
        for (let i = parseInt(stdate) + days[y]; i <= parseInt(endate); i += 7) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    finalresult = result.map((item) => {
        return "2022-06-" + item;
    });
    console.log(finalresult);
}

daysindates(["monday", "tuesday"]);
```

Comment: You need to set `result = []`

Comment: Why in your code 2022-06- is static?

Comment: I made it to work only with same month, OK I am gonna change it

Comment: This doesn't work. The first result is "2022-06-2" which was a Thursday, not Monday or Tuesday. The code isn't indented, there are many undeclared variables, the function name is meaningless, etc.

Comment: It's called with `["monday", "tuesday"]` but the returned dates are Thursdays and Fridays, so no, not "fine".